# Which Hawaii bird makes this call at night?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I'm on Big Island right now and keep hearing this bird starting at 6-7PM every night: https://voca.ro/18XEepbDmpCy. Which bird could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [magic of Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Hawaii/comments/l0fh59/what_is_this_mysterious_bird_on_big_island_that/) I was able to figure out that this is the [Coqui frog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eFvjgMP-LU) rather than a bird. Apparently its an invasive species [on Big Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coqu%C3%AD#Geographic_distribution/invasive_species) and attempts are underway to eradicate them.